# WPF DataGrid ContextMenu causes application to crash

Tags: wpf, datagrid, contextmenu, .net-4.5

I have a WPF DataGrid.ContextMenu XAML defined like so:

```
<DataGrid.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu >
        <MenuItem x:Name="mChangeVessel" Header="Change Vessel" />
        <MenuItem x:Name="mChangeVoyage" Header="Change Voyage" />
    </ContextMenu>
</DataGrid.ContextMenu>
```

VB Handler:

```
Private Sub mChangeVessel_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles mChangeVessel.Click
    Try
        MessageBox.Show("Vessel Changed", "Test Message", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub mChangeVoyage_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles mChangeVoyage.Click
    Try
        MessageBox.Show("Voyage Changed", "Test Message", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error)
    End Try
End Sub
```

On 4 out of 5 pc's I've run my app on, it works fine. On my laptop (where I have done extensive testing of my app and haven't had a problem until now), when I right-click on the datagrid, my app just dies. You can see I tried to add some error handling, but it doesn't get caught there.

I feel like it's a .NET framework dependency issue, but it looks to me like all machines have the latest version (4.7 ish).

Should I target a different .NET Framework version? I am targeting 4.5
What are the .NET "client profile" versions for?

If these .NET Framework questions are barking up the wrong tree, can anyone suggest how I should debug this problem? I don't have Visual Studio on the laptop.

Edit:

I have added the exception from the Windows Application Event Log. Can anyone point me in the right direction to resolving this? I'd like to do a dependency check to make sure my target machine has all the required libraries. What is the best way to do that?

Error:

```
Application: WinnipegWpf.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.ArgumentNullException
   at System.Windows.Automation.Peers.DataGridItemAutomationPeer..ctor(System.Object, System.Windows.Automation.Peers.DataGridAutomationPeer)
   at System.Windows.Automation.Peers.DataGridAutomationPeer.CreateItemAutomationPeer(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Automation.Peers.ItemsControlAutomationPeer.FindOrCreateItemAutomationPeer(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Automation.Peers.DataGridAutomationPeer.RaiseAutomationSelectionEvents(System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.OnSelectionChanged(System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector+SelectionChanger.End()
   at System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.MakeFullRowSelection(ItemInfo, Boolean, Boolean)
   at System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.HandleSelectionForCellInput(System.Windows.Controls.DataGridCell, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean)
   at System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.OnContextMenuOpening(System.Windows.Controls.ContextMenuEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(System.Delegate, System.Object)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(System.Object, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(System.Object, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs, Boolean)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(System.Windows.DependencyObject, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Controls.PopupControlService.RaiseContextMenuOpeningEvent(System.Windows.IInputElement, Double, Double, Boolean)
   at System.Windows.Controls.PopupControlService.ProcessMouseUp(System.Object, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Controls.PopupControlService.OnPostProcessInput(System.Object, System.Windows.Input.ProcessInputEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.RaiseProcessInputEventHandlers(System.Windows.Input.ProcessInputEventHandler, System.Windows.Input.ProcessInputEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(System.Windows.Input.InputEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(System.Windows.Input.InputReport)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.ReportInput(IntPtr, System.Windows.Input.InputMode, Int32, System.Windows.Input.RawMouseActions, Int32, Int32, Int32)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.FilterMessage(IntPtr, MS.Internal.Interop.WindowMessage, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.InputFilterMessage(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority, System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(System.Windows.Interop.MSG ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window)
   at WinnipegWpf.Application.Main()
```

Comment: Have you looked into System Event Log?

Comment: Good call! There are a couple of exceptions in the Application Log actually. "Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, Exception code 0xe0434352" etc. I better do some research on these errors. Thanks for the suggestion! I don't know if it's too early to mark this as the answer? But I think I have some homework now to get me on the way. Cheers

Comment: Development: I found some "unsound" logic in my program, whereby I was calling the data load logic in a Window's Loaded event over and over in a tight loop. Fixing this has stopped the crashing behaviour, so I am happy for now, but the question still remains why it behaved differently on one machine to another. Maybe it ran out of memory? I can't see anything in the event log error to suggest that.